# Visual Studio : User specific output directory

Tags: git, visual-studio, vcxproj

I can't find the answer to my question anywhere so I hope someone can help!

We have an MFC project under Visual Studio 2017, managed under git and we use Sourcetree as a GUI. In the prject, the output directory is defined among other things.
When we run the app in debug mode, each developer wants the binaries to output in a different directory (for me it is C:/MyApp/win64, for my colleague it can be D:/Sources/binaries/foo/...). So each one of us changes the output directory in the project and the annoying thing is that Sourcetree says that we have uncommitted changes which is true.

Small precision : We don't want the directory to be relative to anything and we want to be able to set an absolute path.

So my question is : Is there a way to avoid that ? Like setting the output directory in the .user to overload the value set in the project, or another solution?

Comment: doesn't sound like a git problem.

Comment: I agree, it is more a Visual Studio problem or a lack of ability to overload the VS project with user configuration. Unless I am not aware that it is possible!